# c++ variadic template argument iterating

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generic-programming

I'm pretty inexperienced in such things, but I'm trying to create a template function that evaluates a **n**-variable function at "rotated" argument (see example below) and returns a vector of all these values.

For example for **n**=3 with a function **f**(x,y,z) the returned triple\vector should be

> < **f**(x,0,0), **f**(0,x,0), **f**(0,0,x) >

The naive version of what I need could look like the following (not necessary correct\working)

```
typedef FunctionSignature Function;

template<class Function, size_t Dimensions>
std::array<Function::Out,Dimensions> F(Function::InComponent x)
{
  std::array<Function::Out,Dimensions> Result;

  for (i=0; i<Dimensions; i++)    
     Result[i] = Function::f("rotate((x,0,...,0),i)");

  return Result;
}
```

But how to make the `rotate` thing.

I also hope that the run-time `for` could be somehow be eliminated since `n` is well known in time of compilation.

Comment: Instead of your `f()` function taking an explicit list of values as parameters, have your `f()` function take a vector of values, instead. Populating the vector with values, to be passed as a parameter, becomes trivial. No need to deal with variadic functions.

Comment: 1) I have no problem to make 'f' vector valued I guess ...although it could be redundant when 'n'=1. ....
2) "becomes trivial" doesn't help...
particularly, I'm not sure how it helps to get it done in compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class Function, size_t... Is, size_t... Js>
typename Function::Out call_f(typename Function::InComponent x, 
                              std::index_sequence<Is...>, 
                              std::index_sequence<Js...>) {
    return Function::f((void(Is), 0)..., x, (void(Js), 0)...);
}

template<class Function, size_t Dimensions, size_t... Is>
std::array<typename Function::Out, Dimensions> F(typename Function::InComponent x,
                                                 std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  return {{ call_f<Function>(x, std::make_index_sequence<Is>(),
                                std::make_index_sequence<Dimensions - Is - 1>())... }};
}

template<class Function, size_t Dimensions>
std::array<typename Function::Out,Dimensions> F(typename Function::InComponent x)
{
   return F<Function, Dimensions>(x, std::make_index_sequence<Dimensions>());
}
```

For C++11, search on SO for an implementation of `make_index_sequence`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6603ba8141b10b50).

Comment: Thanks, this looks very nice and exactly what I need! (with a big hope that I know what I need by myself, lol)

Comment: I guess  `(void(Is), 0)...` should be  `(void(Is), Function::InComponent(0) )...` in a fully generic case